# How to recover Linux binaries for safe shutdown after unplugged ssd

Tags: linux, memory

I'm running Arch Linux on an SSD through a usb port (the laptop's internal connecter failed, so this is my alternative). My issue is that every once in a while I bump the cord and the drive becomes unplugged. I quickly plug it back in again, but it already causes issues. My RAM (8 GB) appears to have stored enough to keep everything stable to continue doing what I was doing such as using Firefox and my windowing environment, but anytime I want to do something in the terminal or shut off the computer, I get either I/O errors or binary not found errors.

I was thinking if I could load the systemctl binaries into RAM then I could use the shutdown command to safely shut it off. I've tried preloading everything from /usr/bin, but that doesn't seem to work. Ideally, I'd like to reconnect with the drive and continue as though nothing happened, but I'm not sure if that's possible or the safest thing to do. Is systemd even still running? If it's not, I'm under the impression none of the systemctl commands would work even if they were in RAM.

Comment: @mashuptwice If the drive can't be accessed, there's no safe shutdown. (It doesn't matter what binaries you have in RAM.)