# Suddenly unplugging the hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've installed Linux on an external hard drive. I have Windows on the main/internal HDD.

- What would happen if I would unplug the external hard drive while the
  Linux OS is still running?
- Would this affect my internal HDD?
- Will I be able to access the Linux OS again?
- If not, is the answer the same for Windows?

Comment: Related question: [*How to recover Linux binaries for safe shutdown after unplugged ssd?*](https://superuser.com/q/1130224/432690).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What would happen if I would unplug the external harddrive while the linux is still running?

Your system would "crash" sooner or later. It would still run with whatever is loaded into RAM at the time but as soon as it needs to read/write in a partition that's no longer there, it'll stop working.

> Would this affect my internal hdd?

No.

> Will I be able to access the linux os again?

Maybe, but you may need to manually check for and correct logical errors in the abruptly unplugged drive.

> If not, it's the same for windows?

A [*non sequitur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(logic)).

Comment: _Would this affect my internal hdd?_ *no*  Well, actually it might.  The drive should be fine physically, but your file-system may suffer from corruption if it was partway through a write.

Comment: @Baldrickk The OS running is Linux and installed in an external HDD. Even if it was writing to the (Windows) internal drive that's NOT the drive being unplugged so no, your remark is incorrect. It seems you didn't read the question.

Comment: @MichaelBay Well... It's incredibly unlikely, but there could be some FS-writing code that it was just about to swap in (which was swapped out for some reason) and the removal of the external hard drive prevents it from doing so, thus causing a minor internal disk corruption.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If that was the case we'd also be experiencing corrupted file systems (albeit rarely) whenever a download is interrupted or a copy operation is canceled mid-way but that doesn't happen. Problems (may) occur if the drive being written to is disconnected, not the other way around.

Comment: @MichaelBay On my Windows laptop (NTFS) when a file was open for writing and hadn't been closed, the reported file size was larger than (read: different to) the number of bytes that had yet been written. That's a form of corruption.

Comment: @MichaelBay apologies, yes, I misread.  Though if it causes the OS to sigfault while writing to the Windows disk (e.g. accessing files on that disk) then it could cause corruption.  probably limited to the user files though.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 If that's what you mean by "file *system* corruption" we'll have to disagree. Considering the question as posted, which doesn't even mention unplugging it whilst performing file copies and/or writing to the internal drive, delving into or discussing such abstract scenarios is unproductive and unhelpful.

Comment: @MichaelBay A file being unexpectedly truncated due to a high swappiness and the swap vanishing is a problem. It's unlikely, but not impossible; it's just one of the bad possibilities.

Comment: Unfortunately @wizzwizz4 is correct: filesystem corruption on the internal hard disk is entirely possible. If its filesystem is mounted (and some distros auto-mount all partitions they find), and if the filesystem in question is implemented in a user-space process (which it likely will be, since most if not all modern Linux NTFS implementations run under FUSE), then the scenario wizzwizz4 describes can indeed happen, and the filesystem itself (not just files) can be corrupted. This is entirely different to the "interrupted download" you mentioned, where I agree only the one file is at risk.

Answer (score 3):

> What would happen if I would unplug the external harddrive while the linux is still running?

Some applications would no longer run. If the swap was hosted on the removed disk, some applications would crash, and possibly the whole system would, too.

Additionally, at the next boot the system would require a file system check.

With most current Linux filesystems and distributions, nothing else would happen.

> Would this affect my internal hdd?

If it was *mounted*, yes. At the very least the "Disk Dirty" flag would not be cleared by a clean unmount, so at the next boot Windows would require a disk check, too.

If by "affect" you mean data loss or hardware damage, both are *conceptually possible*, in the same sense that you *could* die of a meteor strike as soon as the disk is unplugged. All three possibilities are equally remote.

This of course refers to data at rest. Any data that was being written to the internal disk when the system crashes is almost surely at least partially lost... but I don't believe you expected anything different.

It also assumes that you're using the latest version of the ntfs-3g Linux module, or an equally mature and stable software that understands NTFS, MFT management, **journaling** and staggered R/W, and properly implements data safety procedures. Otherwise, a kernel crash can do literally *anything* to *any disk physically connected*, including replacing an *unmounted* disk's partition table with pictures of lolcats. Unless you hacked the kernel or whipped up a distribution yourself, chances are that while this uncomfortable situation is absolutely possible, yet **you are not in it**.

> Will I be able to access the linux os again?

In all likelihood, yes. There are conditions and setups that could result in otherwise, but they're unlikely to apply.

> If not, it's the same for windows?

You mean: if you can no longer access Linux, can you still access Windows?

I expect that in both cases you will be able to access *both*, in both cases being required to check the filesystem integrity first.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for real in the past, mostly due to flaky drives.

- Any process that is cached in ram will continue to run
- Any binary that is cached in ram can be run again.  Common ones like `ls` should exist, but the `poweroff` command won't be.   Also any libraries called by the binary need to be cached too.
- Any directory/file tables/inodes need to be cached in memory to get a directory listing.

Common errors when this happens will look like

```
root@server:~$ ls 
ls: reading directory '/root/': Input/output error
```

If you want to test it, install linux on a spare USB drive and hot unplug it.  You could disconnect your windows drive for safety.  Or even boot a live CD ISO in a VM and "eject" it without warning the client.  It should have the same effect.