# Remounting root when disconnected drive

Tags: filesystems

Is it possible to remount the root partition if the drive that it's on is disconnected and then reconnected? Maybe somehow load a staticly linked executable of the mount command on a ram tmpfs during boot and then use that binary to remount the root partition

Comment: Related, unanswered yet: [How to recover Linux binaries for safe shutdown after unplugged ssd?](https://superuser.com/q/1130224/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yeah I have the exact same problem. Internal drive died and external gets unplugged. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to comment on his question

Comment: I just noticed it's from 2016..