# Recover from a cable move on an eSATA disk on Linux

Tags: linux, esata

I've been lately using an external `/home`, which is placed on an eSATA disk.

The problem is after a while I somehow manage to move the cable.
Then I get a bunch of IO errors in the terminal and I have to do a hard reboot (followed by fsck if I'm in the mood for that) (the system won't even power down with `sudo poweroff` after the cable is moved and the IO errors start) or the /home directory stays read only`.

Is there a way to recover from this less drastically. (Unfortunately not even `umount /home` works when in that moved-cable state).

Comment: There is a way: Patience. `sudo poweroff` will work after a while, when all timeouts in all retry queues have expired.

Comment: Somewhat related: [*How to recover Linux binaries for safe shutdown after unplugged ssd?*](https://superuser.com/q/1130224/432690)

Comment: Patience doesn't work :D. Once it happened I left it for like half an hour and the computer was still stuck.